# Scale object to column width in indesign script

Tags: adobe-indesign, script, scale

we have a repetitive task, distributing a logo to the top left of the margin and scaling this to the first column (X columns defined). Is there a script or perhaps point me in the direction of something similar to get going? I'm using the default align Horizontal to margin left/vert top. But it'll be great to scale object first to column dimension.

thanks

Rob

Comment: It's unlikely you will find a script that does exactly what you want. That said you could write that script yourself! Try and if you run into any problems, we'd be happy to take a look and see if we can help.

Comment: I am looking to get going. Been looking through the forums for a while. cheers